# Not receiving UINavigationBarDelegate callbacks

Tags: iphone, protocols

Is there a way to troubleshoot not receiving the NavBarDelegate callbacks?  I tried in a test project to just do:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setDelegate:self];
```

in viewDidLoad and I did receive the callbacks for:

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPushItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    return YES;
}
- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPushItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);    
}

- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    return YES;
}
- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

I did check that my ViewController conforms to this protocol in the interface .

In viewWillAppear:, I check if my class conforms to the protocol with:

```
if ([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UINavigationBarDelegate)]) {
        NSLog(@"yes I conform");
    }
```

And I do get the NSLog message saying my class conforms, but I do not get the callbacks.  As it works in a test project, and it doesn't work here, I'm trying to figure out other ways to troubleshoot this.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: do you push or pop any items?

Comment: Where is 'here' that you mention?

Comment: @Paul de Lange Yes I push and pop like in my test project.  My test project gets the callbacks, but my real project does not.

Answer (score 5):

I am leaving this for future anyone who will encounter this issue:

You need to place these `<UINavigationBarDelegate> protocol methods` inside your Navigation Controller's class, not inside a view controller's class you are working on.

In my case I just have a class NavigationController (subclass of UINavigationController), singleton instance of which: `sharedNavigationController` works for my entire app. I have set it to conform `<UINavigationBarDelegate> protocol` and declared these methods in it. All worked fine since then.